# Azure DevOps - Set Project Permissions using Rest API Access Control List

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to set project permissions of Azure DevOps groups using Azure DevOps RestApi. I tried using Access Control Entries but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    $securityNamespaceId = "52d39943-cb85-4d7f-8fa8-c6baac873819"
    $groupDesc = "vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0yMzY2NjcwMjQwLTIyNDExNTQxMjQtMzEwMzY2MTYyNS0zODgxOTE3ODcxLTEtMzk0MjAxMzY5NS00MTY5ODI4NjEtMjk1MDY4ODE5MC0yMDI0NjY2NTQz"
    $projectId = "12313142-eec0-4c3d-b9b5-44d0c3973b3e"
    $token = "`$PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/$($projectId)"
    $allowMask = 4
    $denyMask = 0
    $bodyInfo = @{
                    token = $token
                    merge = $true
                    accessControlEntries = @{
                            descriptor = $groupDesc
                            allow = $allowMask
                            deny = $denyMask
                            Extendedinfo=  {}               
                    } 
    }| ConvertTo-Json

    $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/<Organization>/_apis/accesscontrolentries/52d39943-cb85-4d7f-8fa8-c6baac873819?api-version=5.0"

    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $bodyInfo -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" 

Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 
73da9e7f-1f9a-4d56-b8ca-f1e9e13513a6.","typeName":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException, Newtonsoft.Json","typeKey":"JsonSerializationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $bodyInfo -Headers $he ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Security.AccessControlEntry]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'accessControlEntries.allow'.

Also, make sure your PAT has the vso.security_manage scope.